Left Mouse Click reverts to Top Orthographic View
I'm a beginner on the steep learning curve. I'm working my way through a tutorial and have reached a road block. When I got to the section on shading of the tutorial, every Left Mouse Click switches my view to Top Orthographic. This happens whatever mode i'm in. Also if I'm in any of the different workspaces - Layout, Shading etc. This issue does not occur in 4.2 But the tutorial I'm trying to follow requires 4.1 as it utilizes Ambient Occlusion and Bloom which have been replaced by Ray Tracing in 4.2.
Using V4.1.0
Mac OS Sonoma 14.5

Your link to those images requires a log-in to Adobe Cloud it seems, so we can't see them. My first instinct would be to go to the Preferences > Keymap >Key Binding and type in "Left Mouse Button" and see if you accidentally added a hotkey to top orthographic. If you did just click the "X" to remove it and it should work.

Thank you for your advice. No luck I'm afraid. Frustrating to say the least.

Ambient occlusion and bloom haven’t been replaced.
